Why a random variable $X$ can be a value $x$ in its own domain e.g. $P(X=x)$?
Knowing that random variable $X$ is defined as a function $X=f:\Omega \rightarrow E$.
Domain $\Omega$ is the set of possible outcomes, and range $E$ is a measurable space such as $\mathbb{R}$. \cite{link}
Does this statement $P(X=x)$ make sense?
My confusions and opinion:

I think $X(x \in \Omega) \in E$
I think that $x \not \in E$
I think X is a set. X cannot be equal to a single scalar $x$ or event $x$.

Now I dont't know from where I get everything wrong. Help please.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here, $x$ is an element of $E$, and "$X=x$" refers to the event ${\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) = x}$, and so $\mathbb P(X = x)$ is the probability of the event consisting of all outcomes under which the value of $X$ is equal to $x$. That's how it makes sense.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer Thank you for such immediate help! It now makes sense to me if $x \in E$ is a numerical representation of one or many outcomes!

Good to be of assistance here.

Indeed $X$ is a function as you mentioned and we have for example $E=\{x|X=x\}$ so
$P(X=x)$ means $P(E)$. That is we can consider $\{X=x\}$ as an event.
